Approach to Fermat's Last Theorem using group theory
I'm trying to solve Fermat's Last Theorem in this way:

Take the equation $(*)$ $x^{q}+y^{q}=z^{q}$ with $q\geq3$ a prime number
Let $p=mq+1$ be another prime number for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$
Define $G_{m}:= \lbrace g \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}:g^{m}\equiv_{p}1  \rbrace$ where $a\equiv_{p}b$ if $p$ divides $b-a$.

Then it's clear that:

$G_{m}$ is a cyclic group and $G_{m}\leq (\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z})^{*}$, where $(\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ is the multiplicative cyclic group
If $g\equiv_{p}a^{q}$ for some integer $a$ such that $p$ doesn't divide $a$, then $g\in G_{m}$ because $g^{m}\equiv_{p}a^{mq}=a^{p-1}\equiv_{p}1$
If $g\in G_{m}$ then $-g\in G_{m}$ because $m$ is even
If $(*)$ has integer solutions and $p$ doesn't divide $xyz$, there exist $g_{1},g_{2},g_{3}$ in $G_{m}$ such that $g_{1}+g_{2}=g_{3} \Rightarrow g_{1}g_{3}^{-1}+g_{2}g_{3}^{-1}=1$. If $g:=g_{1}g_{3}^{-1}$ and $\overline{g}:=-g_{2}g_{3}^{-1}$ then $g=1+\overline{g}$. Therefore, if $(*)$ has integer solutions and $p$ doesn't divide $xyz$, then $G_{m}$ has the following property: $(**)$ there exists a $g\in G_{m}$ such that $g+1\in G_{m}$
If $(*)$ has integer solutions and $(**)$ doesn't hold for $G_{m}$ then $p\mid xyz$
If you find a sequence of natural numbers $m_{1},m_{2},...$ such that $(**)$ doesn't hold for any $G_{m_{k}}$ then, each $p_{k}\mid xyz$, so $xyz$ has to be infinite, therefore there are no integer solutions for $(*)$ (assuming there are infinite primes of the form $mq+1$)

Finally, the question is: is there a result related to the property $(**)$ in algebra?

Why is $m$ even?

@YuqiaoHuang Because if $m$ were odd, $p=mq+1$ would be even and therefore not prime.

If P is a prime and q=2p+1 is also a prime then these primes are called Sophie Germain primes. Using this primes Sophie Germain solved so many cases of Fermat's Last theorem. But how many Sophie Germain primes are there still an open problem. So  p= mq+1 solves FLT finitely many cases, Because P= mq+1 has finitely many primes or Infinitely Many primes ?

Your strategy cannot work. For any prime $p$ and large enough $m$, $(**)$ will fail for $G_m$, that is, there will be $g\in G_m$ such that $g+1$ in $G_m$. Through your argument in point 4, this follows as long as $x^q+y^q\equiv_p z^q$ has solutions with $x,y,z$ not divisible by $p$. This is fairly classical - there is a lovely combinatorial argument using Schur's theorem, you can find a nice exposition of it here.
So unfortunately, this approach doesn't really have any chance of working, since the Fermat's equation will have nontrivial solutions modulo all large enough primes.
